Why could I allow a duplicate on Kotlin's sets?
It is known that the set in Kotlin prohibits the content of duplicates. But I was able to create such a set:
var c = Card2.`2c`
var cards3: Set<Card2> = setOf(c, c)

Why is this acceptable? Or did I misunderstand something in the documentation?
Or am I doing something wrong?
I tried to check also:
var s: Set<String> = setOf("3", "3")

But I didn't see any compilation errors or others.

Did you look at the result? It doesn't contain duplicates.

Yes, I already checked, thanks for the hint

Note that in Java, Set.of("3", "3") would give you an IllegalArgumentException because it doesn't allow duplicate elements. Kotlin, on the other hand, just swallows them.

This question turned out to be my omission.
The set contains, as expected, non-duplicated elements
println(cards3)

printed: [2c]
